# Password Manager for Raspberry (online AND offline access)

Tags: pi-2, password

I'm searching for a good password manager. And yes, i know, google is full with tutorials for that kind of stuff. But all password managers i found, are only online usable. I need a solution where i can store all my password on my raspberry with online access but ALSO to get some kind of access when using offline. A tool which synchronize the stored passwords from my raspberry pi to my computer.

I don't want to store my passwords in a foreign cloud. I want to store them on my raspberry pi. And i also want to have access to my password storage, even when my raspberry is offline.

Comment: I use Keepass2 on Windows and KeepassDroid on my phone (with the file sync'd using Dropbox). It looks like there's a Linux source package at https://sourceforge.net/projects/keepass/files/KeePass%202.x/2.40/KeePass-2.40-Source.zip/download which should run OK on a Raspberry.

Comment: @Dougie No need to build from sources. `keepass2` and `keepassx` (I prefer the latter) are in the repositories.

Comment: "I want to store [my passwords] on my raspberry pi. And i also want to have access to my password storage, even when my raspberry is offline" - Don't your requirements contradict each other?